# Unable to access 'path.scripts'

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting below error in administrative command prompt while running elastic search.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.scripts' (C:\elasticsearch-2.3.1\config\scripts)    
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException: C:\elasticsearch-2.3.1\config\scripts
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:340)    
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:314)    
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:248)    
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:212)    
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:118)    
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupSecurity(Bootstrap.java:196)    
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:167)    
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)    
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)    
Refer to the log for complete error details.
```

Also `C:\elasticsearch-2.3.1\config\scripts` exist. but still I get the error

[image: directory image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that script is a file and not a directory. Delete the file and create a directory with that name.